# Getting The Invalid Hook Call error while using biz charts library

Tags: bizcharts

While using the dependency of the Biz chart i have got this error message.
"Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons"

```
import React from 'react'
import {
    Chart,
    Interval,
    Axis,
    Tooltip,
    Coordinate,
    Label,
    Legend,
    View,
    Guide,
    Shape,
    Facet,
    Util
  } from "bizcharts";
  import DataSet from "@antv/data-set";

function Biz() {
    const data = [
        {
          State: "WY",
          "小于5岁": 25635,
          "5至13岁": 1890,
          "14至17岁": 9314
        },
        {
          State: "DC",
          "小于5岁": 30352,
          "5至13岁": 20439,
          "14至17岁": 10225
        },
        {
          State: "VT",
          小于5岁: 38253,
          "5至13岁": 42538,
          "14至17岁": 15757
        },
        {
          State: "ND",
          "小于5岁": 51896,
          "5至13岁": 67358,
          "14至17岁": 18794
        },
        {
          State: "AK",
          "小于5岁": 72083,
          "5至13岁": 85640,
          "14至17岁": 22153
        }
      ];
      const ds = new DataSet();
      const dv = ds.createView().source(data);
      dv.transform({
        type: "fold",
        fields: ["小于5岁", "5至13岁", "14至17岁"],
        // 展开字段集
        key: "年龄段",
        // key字段
        value: "人口数量",
        // value字段
        retains: ["State"] // 保留字段集，默认为除fields以外的所有字段
      });
  
    return (
        <div>
            <Chart height={400} data={dv.rows} autoFit>
        <Coordinate transposed/>
                <Tooltip shared />
        <Axis
          name="State"
          label={{
            offset: 12
          }}
        />
        <Interval
          adjust={[{ type: 'stack' }]}
          position="State*人口数量"
          color={"年龄段"}
                    style={{
                        fillOpacity:0.75
                    }}
          label={['人口数量', { position: 'middle', offset: 0, style: { fill: '#fff' }, layout: { type: 'limit-in-shape' } }]}
        />
      </Chart>

        </div>
    )
}

export default Biz
```

Here are the dependencies

```
{
  "name": "Biz",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@antv/data-set": "^0.11.8",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.12.0",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.7",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.8.3",
    "bizcharts": "^4.1.14",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "web-vitals": "^1.1.2"
  },
```

While I am running my program I have got the above error.

Answer (score 2):

The invalid hook call is currently an issue with bizcharts (see [open issue on Github](https://github.com/alibaba/BizCharts/issues/1382)).

The problem may have to do with how different react version dependencies are handled with npm, and apparently yarn does a better job ([here](https://blog.csdn.net/qq_46162007/article/details/122553465)'s a discussion). What worked for me and a few others is to uninstall with npm and re-install with yarn:

```
$ npm uninstall bizcharts
$ yarn add bizcharts
```